# How could a Massive Animal Thermoregulate?

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

In my world, there are massive vertebrate creatures that live on the planet's savannahs and rainforests. Alongside others that live in the frigid south pole and deep in the ocean trenches. I'm wondering how these creatures could thermoregulate, specifically externally, but I'm interested in learning about internal stuff too. (I don't know too much about it)

I think it would be really interesting if a Sauropod sized creature could consume massive blocks of ice like gastroliths to cool themselves off. Kinda like a popsicle. The obvious issue with that is that the ice would melt before the creature could consume it, due to the climate. Maybe there some type of cooling magnet or reverse anti-freeze that theoretically exists?

On the topic of the creatures living in the cold, I imagined them to consume fossil fuels and become a bio-furnace, supplementing their dense integument and fat layers, while burping out fire and smoke too.

Comment: Have you researched how large real-world vertebrates that live in hot climates (eg elephants) or cold climates (eg polar bears, whales) regulate their temperature?  What is the problem with those strategies?

Comment: Massive animals can easier thermoregulate because their mass. Maybe overheating might be more a problem for them. But the more typical problem is not the overheating but keep the warm.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the surface regions- you can do the traditional thing there and sweat- or cool of by coating yourself in moisture (water/mud).

The problem is the heat deep inside, that gets transported around with the bloodstream. So the most natural thing would be giant "cooling" crests exposing the blood-vessels to wind/air allowing the warmth to be radiated away.

Finally there is the possibility for a internal "sweat" system, as in there is 2nd system of highly saline fluids, that does nothing but take up surplus body-heat.

When to much heat is stored, the carrying fluid is ejected- either via a external gland into the air- or (if infrared sighted predators are around) - into the ground.

Oh, one more idea- the beast eats a food, that is endothermic to digest. Meaning, to split up the foods chemistry into useful components, all the heat is used up.

Comment: I agree that some kind of high-area cooling surfaces would make sense. Dimetrodon sails and Stegosaurus plates are believed to have served a thermoregulatory purpose, as do elephant ears.

Comment: Maybe a addition to the thermo dynamics. A seemingly paradox effect is - you want it to have a darker outer layer, to create a chimney effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_effect . The creature could then regulate the cooling or heating, not only by constricting blood flow, but also by turning the surface into the sun during grazing.